# How to properly smooth detected faces position and size at 30 FPS?

Tags: avfoundation, face-detection, core-image

I want to filter the position and size of the detected face, to smooth in along the time.

Problem is the video is about 30 FPS but the method that calls the face detection:
captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection
Is called every 5 times per second, and then the rectangle (a CGRect ) is send to the main thread to be drawn using:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
So, it does not matter if I apply a low pass filter or kalman filter in that part of the program because it updates the rectangle 5 times per second, that’s the reason I see the rectangle like vibrating or with noise in its position.

What should I do?

Should I add something like a timer (NSTimer) at 30 ticks per second or similar in order to apply the filter there?
What program architecture would you use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with avfoundation, but poking around the API you might be able to use this:
addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock: on AVPlayer

You can give it a 1/30 CMTime, and it will be timed to the video rather than absolute time.

Then it's a matter of coordinating with the output capture delegate. It sounds like they may be processed by different threads(?), so you'll probably want to create some kind of thread safe queue data structure to pass events from the periodic time observer to the output capture. That kind of thing doesn't appear to be a built in library, so you might have to get creative with this piece.

Comment: I didn't know addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval. I will try it and let you know. Thanks. BTW: I don't have a clear idea about the coordination, any concrete suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will work: https://code.google.com/p/plactorkit/
Especially this call with timeout 0: http://plactorkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/plactorkit-1.0/docs/interface_p_l_actor_kit.html#ab754a77e621a71d5f026ebf7b7cd34a

Comment: Plactorkit says it's inter-thread message passing, but in this situation I don't think you want to assume one way or another whether these calls are on the same thread. So you might try to verify that this will still work even if messages are being sent and received on the same thread.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I have to try that.